# Custom multiplayer inboxIntent

Tags: android, google-play-games

The developer website suggests that custom inboxIntent can be used by referencing them as "Default user interface", but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#handling_invitations

Could someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Mitch, in the **Realtime Multiplayer** documentation, there is a section about **Inbox UI**, maybe it's a google mistake by not including it in **Turnbased Multiplayer** documentation.

So you must retrieve the Inbox `Intent` using the `getInboxIntent(GoogleApiClient apiClient)` and then start the Inbox `Activity` using the `startActivityForResult`. Like:

```
// request code (can be any number, as long as it's unique)
final static int RC_INVITATION_INBOX = 10001;

// launch the intent to show the invitation inbox screen
Intent intent = Games.Invitations.getInvitationInboxIntent(mClient);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);
```

Take a look at [From the Invitation Inbox](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#from_the_invitation_inbox) in Google Play Games Multiplayer Realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find how to request lists of all running and finished matches:

[TurnBasedMultiplayer - onTurnBasedMatchesLoaded does not get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429654/turnbasedmultiplayer-onturnbasedmatchesloaded-does-not-get-called)